# What does this tiny window balcony spotted in Zurich stand for?

Tags: switzerland, factoids, architecture, zurich

Watching photos made in Zurich this September, I noticed strange window construction. What does this red wooden box stand for? It's too small to be a balcony - at least for adult human, probably it's done for infants or cats? Another idea - probably it's old-fashioned refrigerator from old times? I have not succeeded trying to find information about it in the Internet.

[image]

Comment: @Willeke seems like there is glassed window inside as well

Comment: I've notices similar constructions elsewhere in Zurich as well, so they are relatively common. There are glass windows both on the inside (towards the appartment) and on the outside. I've assumed that they were used to keep food cold, but I am not sure.

Comment: Strangely, one small pane on the right flank is open.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I thought about cooling food too, but if it's designed for food, not clear why there is no shelves (like in refrigerator) and why it's transparent (food inside would stay cool longer in dark place without sun light)

Comment: @WeatherVane yes and it's quite low

Comment: No idea for sure but my theory: These are flats above shops. Traditionally shop owners would live above their shop. Perhaps it is a display cabinet for the shop's wares?

Comment: @theotherone thank you so mush for your brilliant idea! I was missing that there is a shop underneath and I found it's name! Using shop's name I found another photos of the same building and guess what I see inside this construction? Flowers!

Comment: I don't think this is any kind of travelling question. I think it falls in the ["programming in a boat"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) category that's been discussed in the StackOverflow blog. It's interesting but I think it's a better fir for Quora where you can ask anything. That said, I'm not going to play SE cop and vote it down or try to close it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that it's for growing flowers and vegetables, simply a small greenhouse. They are sometimes called Greenhouse Windows or Garden Windows.

Because they have windows on 3 sides they'll let in as much sun as possible. They are most effective if put on windows facing south or north.

Being literally on a window you can take the plants indoors during colder nights and days and then put them back out when the sun is shining.

They could double as food storage during longer cooler periods and maybe as ovens during summer.

[image: A greenhouse on a window with flowers arranged.]

[image: An indoor view]

Comment: That sound reasonable, thank you for the answer! I like this version the most for the moment, trying to find proofs

Comment: Thanks to the comments - I found another photos of the same building! And on the most of them I can see flowers inside of the construction! [one](https://www.hellozurich.ch/cms/cache/90e58d5c61be54c92bf4e08ee803d79c.jpg) [two](https://i.imgur.com/E5gwPAn.png) [three](https://i.imgur.com/qJngncb.jpg) Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

It's a *[bay window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_window)* or *[Oriel window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriel_window)*, they are pretty common in German- and English-speaking areas.

- They have an ornamental role
- They allow to look left and right of the building (instead of just in front)
- They allow more light to enter the room

Comment: Since it doesn't reach the ground, it also belongs to a subset of bay windows called 'oriel windows' - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriel_window

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see discrepancy between _bay windows_ and construction I posted above. _Bay windows_ usually a part of building, they are  extending internal room for the purposes you described. Usually they are made from the same material as building walls, but here I see clearly that this construction is simple addition to existing window. It doesn't look like it was designed as part  of building initially.

Comment: You could add that the floor of such a window makes up for a cozy and bright spot to sit for reading (possibly equipped with some cushions).

Comment: @asdfex probably it's not clear from photo, but this windows are not human height high, it's regular windows, height is about 100-110cm